# Javascript Donate Button Paypal

Tags: google-chrome, paypal, google-chrome-extension

I have created a Chrome Extension to which I've added a Donate Button using bootstrap to create the button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="donate">Donate</button>
```

Through the extension, I have it open a new tab when clicking on the button

```
 $('#donate').click(function () {
            chrome.tabs.create({
                url: 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=MY_EMAIL'
            });
        });
```

Yet I am stuck on how to implement the following bit of code. When I click my button using the link above it opens up a gibberish page meanwhile the bottom set of code takes me to the donation page. How would I use the code underneath to tweak to my set? Thanks

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=MY_EMAIL" 
    data-button="donate" 
    data-name="Spot-A-Voice"
></script>
```

Comment: Any reason you can't use it the same way it works in your extension page?

Comment: @source.rar Well for the code that works, when I copy the same code and try and insert it into my popup for the extension, it can't be found. It doesn't seem to get along well with bootstrap I guess? Another reason being I don't have my html files handling any responsiveness and taking care of everything through my .js file and would like to maintain it that way just for the purpose of keeping it similar.

Answer (score 0):

Well the working code you've shown is a script tag not an 'a href' so its not the same thing (it's probably using JSONP that is executed in the context of your page). So unless paypal has a html button option and provide you with the related javascript (which they probably might), I would suggest you use the script tag in your html page.